# What ConsistencyLevel to use with Cassandra counter tables?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table counting around 1000 page views per second. What  read and write ConsistencyLevel should I use with it? I am using the Cassandra Thrift client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carlo has more or less the right idea. But you have to balance it with your use case.

I work in the game industry and we use cassandra for player data. It is quite heavily bound by the read-modify-write pattern which is not the strong suit of cassandra. But we also have some functionality that are Write heavy (thousands of writes for a few reads a day).

This is my opinion, based upon experience, of how you should use the consistency levels.

Write + Read at QUORUM means that before returning for both operations it will wait for a majority of nodes in the cluster to confirm the operation. It is the solution I use when Read and Writes are roughly at the same frequency. (Player data blob)

Write One + Read All is useful for something very write heavy. We use this for high scores for examples (write often read every 5 minutes for regenerating the high score table of the whole game)
 You could use Write Any if you do not care about the data that much (non critical logs comes to mind).

The only use case I could come up for the Write All + Read One would be messaging or feeds with periodical checks for updates. Chats and messaging seem a good fit for that since Cassandra does not have a subscription/push functionality to it.

Write & Read ALL is a bad implementation. It IS a WASTE of resource as you will get the same consistency as if you were using one of the three set up I mentioned above.

A final note about Write ANY vs. Write ONE : ANY only confirms that anything in the cluster has received the mutation, but ONE confirms that it has been applied at least by one node. ANY is not safe as it could return without error even if all the nodes responsible for that mutation are down, or any other condition that could make the mutation fail after reception. It is also slightly quicker (I only use it as an async dump for logs that are not critical) that is its only advantage, but do not trust the response at 100%.

A good reference to study this subject about cassandra is http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/dml/data_consistency

Comment: I take it there aren't any special concerns for the `counter` data type, which is what the question asked about?

Comment: Upvoted because this answer is at least correct for non-`counter` data types.

Comment: @GordonGustafson do you have examples about this behaving differently for counters? My answer is two years old and since then I have not had a professional project that required me to dig deeper into cassandra. I would welcome any new update on this. I am genuinely interested in more knowledge.

Comment: In Cassandra 2.1 a table that has *any* `counter` columns must have *only* `counter` columns, except for the partition and clustering keys. I can't find any reference saying that ConsistencyLevels work *differently* for `counter` columns, so I suspect your answer is correct, despite the fact that counters are a fairly 'special' Cassandra datatype.

Comment: @GordonGustafson in cassandra Consistency levels have nothing to do with the datatype but regard how to choose which value to listen to as the current valid value. For that cassandra trusts the timestamp. When you ask  at consistency level ALL your client will wait to hear from all instances and will choose the value with the most recent timestamp as valid. Quorum works the same except you wait for a majority of nodes, One and Any wait for the first value returned.

Comment: @GordonGustafson on writes it is a matter of waiting for a number of instances to acknowledge the mutation as applied/received (any and one matters more in that instance).

Answer (score 2):

If you want always be consistent at any read the rule is

(write consistency level + read consistency level) > replication factor.

So you could

```
Write All + Read All (worst solution)
Write One + Read All (second-worst solution)
Write All + Read One (probably faster solution)
Write Quorum + Read Quorum (imho, best solution)
```

I want remember that if a node of RF is down during the r/w operation the operation will fail so I'd avoid the CL ALL.

Regards, Carlo

Answer (score 0):

Based on their document (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_counters_c.html), consistency level ONE is recommended. I guess some sort of merging is used to resolve conflict for counter columns, instead of usual last write win. That's likely why setting a value is not allowed.